# methods to give wget range requests to download a video file

Tags: linux, unix

I am trying to use wget to download video files within a particular bitrate range ? How can use wget request to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ffprobe to get the information about the video, parse just the bitrate and use if statement to wget.